# How to enumerate with capital latin or greek letters without the apostrophe?

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

I tried to do this with enumitem package as such:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
.
.
\begin{document}
.
.
\begin{enumerate}[labels=\Alph*]
\item blah...
\item 2timesblah...
\end{enumerate}
.
.
\end{document}
```

But it will insist to add after every letter an apostrophe, like "A'".
Even if I write it this way:

```
\begin{enumerate}[A.]
\item blah...
\item 2timesblah...
\end{enumerate}
```

the apostrophe is still there but before the dot. Actually, it will be there before anything:
"A'.", "A')" etc.

What can I do?

Comment: Please always post a **complete** small document. That is much more useful than mere fragments, especially when contaminated by dots in the preamble!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The “apostrophe” is called, in `greek.ldf`, `\textdexiakeraia` and, as far as I know, it is the traditional way for denoting alphabetic numerals in Greek: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_numerals that has it in the description of “modern usage”.

If you don't want it for a specific `enumerate` environment, you can do like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\let\textdexiakeraia\relax\Alph*]
\item blah...
\item 2timesblah...
\end{enumerate}

\Alph{page}

\end{document}
```

The final line is for showing that other usages of `\Alph` are unaffected.

[image]

If you want to disable the `\textdexiakeraia` altogether, add

```
\renewcommand{\textdexiakeraia}{}
```

to your document preamble. No `\let\textdexiakeraia\relax` will be necessary any more.

Comment: I wrote exactly this `\documentclass{article} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[greek]{babel} \usepackage{enumitem} \renewcommand{\textdexiakeraia}{} \begin{document} \begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*] \item blah... \item 2timesblah... \end{enumerate} \end{document}` but it won't "relax" the apostrophe. Then I write the exact same thing on **www.writelatex.com** and it works like you said. What is the problem here?

Comment: @Teo Try `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\textdexiakeraia}{}}`

Comment: I tried this too but still won't work. How could this be happening? Could this be a matter of editor? I use TeXworks. It's OK though if I can't work this out I can copy my final code on writelatex. But this is strange, really.

Comment: @Teo My feeling is that you're running an outdated TeX distribution. Can you tell which one?

Comment: I have miktex-portable-2.9.5105 if that's what you're asking me. I just downloaded that and realized it has a built in TeXeditor. Is this outdated? Or the version of MiKTeX is different from the one of TeX?

Comment: @Teo Can you try updating all the MiKTeX packages? There have been several improvements in the Greek related packages, so this could be the cause.

Comment: I just updated everything but still it won't work, neither `\renewcommand{\textdexiakeraia}{}` nor `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\textdexiakeraia}{}}` anyway it's really nothing I can do it in another editor just for this one. Thank you very much for your great help!

Answer (score 2):

For Latin capital letters, you could use this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\foreignlanguage{british}{\Alph*}]
\item blah
\item 2timesblah
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: Latin caps for enumeration]