# Problem with changing enumeration

Tags: compiling, enumerate

I want to change the standard enumeration (arabic numbers) in `enumeration` environment with the greek lowercase alphabet, using `enumitem` package.

I also use `XeLateX` engine to compile my document. The problem is that, when I use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xgreek,enumitem}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFS Artemisia}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=modern]{greek}

\begin{document}    
\begin{enumerate}[label=\let\textdexiakeraia\relax(\alph*)]
      \item bla bla 
      \item bla bla
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error (from my log file):

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\labelenumi ->\let \textdexiakeraia 
                                    \relax (\alph *)
l.120 ...label=\let\textdexiakeraia\relax(\alph*)]

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

LaTeX Info: Redefining \anw@print on input line 121.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `EU1/GFSArtemisia(0)/m/sl' in size <10.95> not a
vailable
(Font)              Font shape `EU1/GFSArtemisia(0)/m/it' tried instead on inpu
t line 122.
```

However, there is no errors when I simply use `label=(\alph*)` option.

Comment: Do you want to remove `\textdexiakeraia` only in `enumerate` labels or from all counter representations using `\alph`?

Comment: [Like this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173534/4778)?

Comment: Please, add a full example: the question linked by Alenanno refers to usage of `babel`, you perhaps are using Polyglossia.

Comment: @egreg I want to remove `\textdexiakeraia` only in that `enumerate` environment

Comment: @Yorgos The need for a minimal example remains

Comment: @Alenanno From that question I got `textdexiakeraia` option. However, It doesn't work in my case.

Comment: @Yorgos It'd be way easier and faster if you posted a MWE as egreg asks (including the packages you're using that are related to this question).

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: You have not loaded the `enumitem`-package (at least not in you MWE).

Comment: @Sveinung sorry, my mistake... I forgot to loaded in that MWE

Comment: The error message indicates that the `textdexiakeraia`-command is not defined. Perhaps it is something wrong with the font definition? Not defined in `fontspec`? The answer Alananno is referring to in second comment, is using pdflatex, not xelatex.

Comment: @Sveinung I tried with other fonts (e.g. Liberation Serif, Linux Libertine O) and the error remains...

Comment: Indicating that `textdexiakeraia`is not defined when you are using xelatex, fontspec and polyglossia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `xgreek` package defines Greek numerals in a quite contorted way, that makes it difficult to change the representation.

Here's code that should work better *and* allowing locally to change the representation by omitting the numeral sign.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xgreek,enumitem}
\setmainfont{GFS Artemisia}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=modern]{greek}

\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd{\anw@true}{\let\ifanw@\iftrue}
\renewrobustcmd{\anw@false}{\let\ifanw@\iffalse}\anw@false
\newrobustcmd{\noanw@true}{\let\ifnoanw@\iftrue}
\newrobustcmd{\noanw@false}{\let\ifnoanw@\iffalse}\noanw@false
\renewrobustcmd{\anw@print}{\ifanw@\ifnoanw@\else\numer@lsign\fi\fi}
\newrobustcmd{\noanw}{\noanw@true}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\noanw\alph*)]
\item bla bla bla
\item bla bla
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]